# Add a "button" next to a column header

Tags: apex, dynamic-visualforce, pageblocktable

Probably I'm refering to a commandLink.

```
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!blabla}" var="bleble">
                <apex:column headerValue="Priority" value="{!1}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!2}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Oportunity/Account" value="{!3}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

What would be an option to add a commandLink to the headerValue? I need to do a sort atm.

Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `apex:facet` to do this.

```
<apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header">Priority <apex:commandLink action="{!action}" value="Go!"/></apex:facet>
    {!1}
</apex:column>
```

There is more detail on `apex:facet` in the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_facet.htm).

Comment: Thanks man, really what I needed, simple and to the point.